# Conditional Formating a specific hours range

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I've been breaking my head on this for the last couple of hours and i can't figure it out.

I'm trying to make sure that the cell between my time range are not coloured in, the rest should be red. Here you can see a picture that shows what my conditional formatting does at this time. It does it for some times but not for everything

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBD2l.png

If someone could help me thanks very much!

Comment: Could I have some more information? Which times does it show and which ones doesn't it? Can you include the row & column headers in the screenshot?

Comment: Please post a screenshot in which we can see the row and column headers.

Comment: https://imgur.com/PEe5fXo

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your start and end times, the ones that don't work have a start time *after* the end time. For example row 4: Start is 20 and End is 1) This means that the check won't work, as it colours in all the rows less than 20 and all the rows greater than 1. Remove both conditions and try the following (horrible) formulae instead:

```
MOD(HOUR(G$3)-7,24) < MOD(HOUR($E4)-7,24))

MOD(HOUR(G$3)-7,24) >= MOD(HOUR($F4)-7,24)
```

First, we convert the times into numbers using the `HOUR` function. Then in order to get around the times being smaller at the end, we subtract the first time (7 hours) and divide by 24 and take the remainder (this is what the `MOD` function does). It's a bit of a headache to work through, but will give the right results.

Comment: Do i put these formulae as the formula for the conditional formatting? Because they dont do anything there

Comment: Yes that’s right - add them as the rule formula, replacing G$3<$E4 and G$3>$F4 respectively. Leave the ranges as they are.

Comment: Happy new year! I had some time and reconstructed your spreadsheet and worked out the issue with my original answer. Have edited the formulae in the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to show you a generic example below which matches with your case ,

with my example you need to add this simple formula and adjust as per your need.

> =AND(G$6>=$E7,G$6<=$F7)

P.S - I have the red color other way around but you can figure this out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: used yours and tried to adjust it and it still doesnt work :(

Comment: I can't open your image , add your screenshot in the question.